# AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'get_doc_id'

Tags: python, csv, large-language-model, knowledge-graph, graph-store-protocol

My Application : load CSV file into knowledge graph(using KnowledgeGraphIndex )and use LLM(HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-beta) to retrieve answers from graph store(SimpleGraphStore).

My Problem : I want to pass multiple CSV files into knowledge graph ,
I am using CSVLoader , when i run knowledgeGraphIndex ,
I am getting this error :AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'get_doc_id'

This is how I am laoding CSV :

```
`from langchain.document_loaders import CSVLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
csv_loader = CSVLoader("/content/Train-Set.csv")
data = csv_loader.load()

splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(separator = "\n",
                                chunk_size=500, 
                                chunk_overlap=0,
                                length_function=len)
documents = splitter.split_documents(data)`
```

And this is my KnowledgeGraphIndex :

```
`index = KnowledgeGraphIndex.from_documents(
   documents,
 storage_context=storage_context,
   include_embeddings=True,
   max_triplets_per_chunk=2,
   embed_model=embed_model,

)``
```

Comment: This code does not use `get_doc_id` anywhere, therefore the error must be happening elsewhere, in some other code that you have not shown us. It is very hard to help when you do not show us the code where the actual error happens. Please update the question and add the full error traceback message, so we can see where the error actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Document` from `langchain.docstore`, and creating document with this class:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import CSVLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from llama_index.core import KnowledgeGraphIndex

csv_loader = CSVLoader("/content/Train-Set.csv")
data = csv_loader.load()
documents = []
splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(separator="\n",
                                 chunk_size=500,
                                 chunk_overlap=0,
                                 length_function=len)
docs = splitter.split_documents(data)

# Assign a unique identifier to each document
for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
    new_doc = Document(
        page_content=doc.page_content,    )
    documents.append(new_doc)

index = KnowledgeGraphIndex.from_documents(
    documents,
    include_embeddings=True,
    max_triplets_per_chunk=2,
)
```